# How to kill a running EL pipeline in Meltano

Tags: airflow, meltano

When running an Extract/Load pipeline with Meltano, what's the best way (or ways) to kill a running job?

Generally these would be run via Airflow but would be nice to have a process that worked also with bare `meltano elt` and/or `meltano run` invocations from orphaned terminal sessions, which might not be able to be canceled simply by hitting `Ctrl+C`.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

The workaround is to hit `Ctrl+C` while the job is running - you will see a message like `Another 'dev:tap-postgres-to-target-snowflake:dev' pipeline is already running which started at 2023-03-20 18:34:49.615984. To ignore this check use the '--force' option.`

You can wait for 5 minutes (stale detection time) before running again or you can run the command using the `--force` flag to omit the above message. The first `meltano run` after the stale detection time will automatically mark the job as [failed](https://meltano.com/blog/now-available-meltano-v1-66-0/).